# Implement opt-in Facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I've implemented a facebook like button into my (html) website. Now german data protection laws want webpages to be opt-in. Other websites do this by not immediately showing the facebook like but instead showing a button saying "activate facebook button" and when this button is clicked they replace it with the real facebook button.
So it requires two clicks, but this is ok for me. An example is [this webpage](http://www.stefangroenveld.de/2011/mein-repertoire-als-hochzeitsfotograf/).

I know html and php but got no clues about javascript (yet). I'd like to know how to implement this: how can I replace the fake button with the facebook one upon clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in their source, they site is using a function they called `button2iframe` - here it is:

```
function button2iframe(id,link){
        //alert(id);
        var substr = link.split("?");
        var url = substr[0];
        substr.reverse();
        substr.pop();
        substr.reverse();
        var params = substr.join("?");
        params = params.split("&");
        var k;
        var param = "";
        var paramname = "";
        for( var k=0; k<params.length; k++ ) {
            param = params[k].split("=");
            if(param.length>1){
                if(param.length>2){
                    paramname = param[0];
                    param.reverse();
                    param.pop();
                    param.reverse();
                    param[1] = param.join("=");
                    param[0] = paramname;
                }
                param[1] = encodeURIComponent(param[1]);
            }
            params[k] = param.join("=");
        }
        params = params.join("&");
        link = url+"?"+params;
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#"+id).html($('<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="'+link+'" id="iframe_'+id+'"/>'));
        });
    }
```

And this is what the associated markup for the facebook button looks like:

```
<li class="wpsoptin_facebook" id="wpsoptin_facebook_39429">
    <div class="wpsoptin_medium">
    <a class="wpsoptin_sharerlink" href="javascript:button2iframe('wpsoptin_facebook_39429','FACEBOOK LIKE BUTTON IFRAM URL GOES HERE')">Facebook aktivieren</a>
    <div class="wpsoptin_sharerend"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This code requires you include jQuery in your site as well.

Comment: I just noticed I really got no clue about js - I don't even know where to put the function in the html file :/

Comment: Seems these things go into script-tags. Makes sense :) Thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

try this if you dont want to use jquery, just remove the couple of line provided Nathan Anderson good answer

```
    //jQuery(function ($) {
       // $("#"+id).html($());

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="'+link+'" id="iframe_'+id+'"/>'

    ///});
```

Comment: I don't understand: I should try your code when I don't want to use jQuery??

Comment: @Sam the code snippet i posted dose what jquery would do, but you still need to use what Nathan Anderson posted and comment out what have and add my snippet, dose that make sence?

Comment: So this is not an answer to the question but instead an addendum to Nathan Andersons Question? Confusing, I'm used to SO Answers to stand on their own, since the other answer might move, be deleted or changed.

Comment: @Sam you are correct, i didnt write the code Nathan posted i just made a alteration so i didnt want to post the full code

Comment: Ah yes, now I see where your alteration is supposed to be in his code, thanks.

Comment: @Sam you could mark my answer useful by voting it up if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I hesitate because your answer can not stand on its own, and therefore is only useful in combination with the other answer. This is confusing for someone looking for an answer, so I decided not to upvote, sorry. Maybe if you edit your answer so it is complete in itself?